# Не получается создать копирующий конструктор для шаблонного класса

Tags: c++

```
template <class FirstType, class SecondType>
struct Pair
{
    Pair(const FirstType& first, const SecondType& second)
        : first(first), second(second)
    {}
    Pair(const Pair<FirstType, SecondType>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second) {}
    Pair(const Pair<const FirstType, SecondType>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second) {}

    FirstType first;
    SecondType second;
};

int main()
{
    Pair<int, int> a(1, 1);
    Pair<const int, int> a_copy(a);
}
```

> error: multiple overloads of 'Pair' instantiate to the same signature
> 'void (const Pair<const const int, int> &)'

UPD:

Нашел конечно одно решение:

```
template<class Costyl1, class Colsyl2>
    Pair(const Pair<Costyl1, Colsyl2>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second) {}
```

но мне потом не охото получать сюрприз, когда из  Pair<double, double> случайно сделаю копию  Pair<int, int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, именно *копирующий* конструктор (`Pair(const Pair<FirstType, SecondType>& src)`) писать не смысла, компилятор сгенерирует его за вас. И сгенерированный конструктор не будет конфликтовать со вторым (если у них совпадут типы параметров, копирующий просто не создастся).

Во-вторых, второй конструктор у вас написан так, чтобы создавать пару с неконстантными элементами из пары с первым константным, а вы пытаетесь сделать обратное.

Наверное вы хотели вот это:

```
Pair(const Pair<std::remove_cv_t<FirstType>, std::remove_cv_t<SecondType>>& src)
    : first(src.first), second(src.second)
{}
```

Но мне больше нравится решение с шаблоном. Оно более универсальное - позволит создавать пару с неконстантными элементами из пары с константными, без написания тучи разных конструкторов.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
Pair(const Pair<A, B>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second) {}
```

> не охото получать сюрприз, когда из Pair<double, double> случайно сделаю копию Pair<int, int>

Тогда добавьте проверку:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
Pair(const Pair<A, B>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<FirstType>, std::remove_cv_t<A>> &&
        std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<SecondType>, std::remove_cv_t<B>>,
        "Types must differ only in cv-qualifiers.");
}
```

Или так:

```
template <typename A, typename B, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<FirstType>, std::remove_cv_t<A>> &&
    std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<SecondType>, std::remove_cv_t<B>>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
Pair(const Pair<A, B>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second)
{}
```

Или так: (C++20 или новее)

```
template <typename A, typename B> requires
    std::same_as<std::remove_cv_t<FirstType>, std::remove_cv_t<A>> &&
    std::same_as<std::remove_cv_t<SecondType>, std::remove_cv_t<B>>
Pair(const Pair<A, B>& src) : first(src.first), second(src.second)
{}
```